# Can't stream H.264 video from Logitech C525 with VLC on BeagleBone Black?

Tags: debian, streaming, vlc, beagleboneblack, logitech

I want to stream a H.264 encoded video using a C525 webcam and a BeagleBone Black board (running Debian).

This is my command:

```
cvlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0:width=1280:height=720:fps=30 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=H264,vb=2000,acodec=none}:rtp{dst=IP_ADDRESS,port=8004,mux=ts}'
```

It work on my PC but it does not work on my BeagleBone board.

Below is the log output of 2 cases. On my PC:

```
......
[0x7ff9a0000be8] main input debug: `v4l2:///dev/video0:width=1280:height=720:fps=30' successfully opened
[0x7ff9a0000be8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7ff9a0000be8] main input debug: switching to sync mode
[0x7ff99c000bd8] main stream output debug: adding a new sout input (sout_input:0x7ff9940008c0)
[0x7ff99c0084d8] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: creating video transcoding from fcc=`YUY2' to fcc=`H264'
[0x7ff9940009c8] main generic debug: looking for decoder module matching "any": 39 candidates
[0x7ff9940009c8] main generic debug: using decoder module "rawvideo"
[0x7ff994000e18] main encoder debug: looking for encoder module matching "any": 17 candidates
[0x7ff9a0000be8] main input debug: Buffering 33%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff99401c140] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7ff99401c140] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7ff99401c140] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1,00:0,00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=8 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=2000 ratetol=1,0 qcomp=0,50 qpmin=3 qpmax=51 qpstep=3 ip_ratio=1,25 aq=1:1,00
[0x7ff994000e18] avcodec encoder debug: found encoder H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)
[0x7ff994000e18] main encoder debug: using encoder module "avcodec"
[0x7ff994000e18] main encoder debug: removing module "avcodec"
[libx264 @ 0x7ff99401c140] final ratefactor: 21,01
[0x7ff9a0000be8] main input debug: Buffering 66%
[0x7ff9a0000be8] main input debug: Stream buffering done (301 ms in 298 ms)
[0x7ff9a0000be8] main input debug: Decoder buffering done in 0 ms
[0x7ff99c0084d8] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: decoder aspect is 1.777778:1
[0x7ff99c0084d8] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: source pixel aspect is 1.000000:1
[0x7ff99c0084d8] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: scaled pixel aspect is 1.000000:1
[0x7ff99c0084d8] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: source 1280x720, destination 1280x720
[0x7ff99c0084d8] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: encoder aspect is 1280:720
[0x7ff99401c1d8] main filter debug: looking for video filter2 module matching "any": 55 candidates
[0x7ff99401c1d8] swscale filter debug: 1280x720 chroma: YUY2 -> 1280x720 chroma: I420 with scaling using Bicubic (good quality)
[0x7ff99401c1d8] main filter debug: using video filter2 module "swscale"
[0x7ff99c0084d8] main stream out debug: Filter 'Swscale' (0x7ff99401c1d8) appended to chain
[0x7ff99c0084d8] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: destination (after video filters) 1280x720
[0x7ff994000e18] main encoder debug: looking for encoder module matching "any": 17 candidates
[libx264 @ 0x7ff994022fc0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7ff994022fc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7ff994022fc0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7ff994022fc0] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1,00:0,00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=8 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=10 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=2000 ratetol=1,0 qcomp=0,50 qpmin=3 qpmax=51 qpstep=3 ip_ratio=1,25 aq=1:1,00
[0x7ff994000e18] avcodec encoder debug: found encoder H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)
[0x7ff994000e18] main encoder debug: using encoder module "avcodec"
[0x7ff99c003fc8] main mux debug: adding a new input
[0x7ff99c003fc8] mux_ts mux debug: adding input codec=h264 pid=68
[0x7ff99c003fc8] mux_ts mux debug: new PCR PID is 68
```

On BeagleBone:

```
......
[0xb51005f8] main input debug: `v4l2:///dev/video0:width=1280:height=720:fps=30' successfully opened
```

I think the BeagleBone is missing the video encoder so it can not transcode video to H264, however the log doesn't show any information about it. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try to power on the BeagleBone with an power suply of 5v , 2A